# Ansible vars at an inventory file level

Tags: environment-variables, ansible

I understand that we can have vars for particular hosts, and particular groups, how would I idiomatically do the same on a per inventory file basis.

I have 3 inventory files for dev/staging/prod. What is the best way to set vars for these environments. examples would be the stage itself, to be set into `/etc/environment` for rails, or API keys, or etc.

At this point I have 1 host per env, so I can just set it as host vars, but eventually I wouldn’t be able to scale that.. so I figure there has to be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are unsure how to group hosts and have variables (and perhaps tasks) apply to a group.

Take a look at [group_vars and host_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#group-variables). This is great for overriding defaults. Here's an example:

```
group_vars/all:
MAX_MEMORY = 16gb

group_vars/dev
MAX_MEMORY = 2gb
```

Alternately, you can put "[group variables](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#group-variables)" in your hosts file(s).

Generally speaking, I'd recommend having one playbook; the recipe that you run on dev/QA/production should be as identical as possible to production.

Comment: Can i set up different group vars for different inventory files? I am having a hard time to understand why there is no clean way to do environment vars. If I try to follow the last line, the differences among the envs will be ideally only in the hosts and other environment vars, atleast at the application level. perhaps your last point of putting group vars in inventory files is what I am looking for. Now that I think of it.. most such vars end up being host specifications.. different LBs for different environments, etc.. perhaps thats why this is not so common..

Comment: Setting the environment is still something that rails requires, not sure whats the right way to do that with ansible.. probably `[all:vars]`